# Set static ip as Ubuntu 16.04 guest

Tags: 16.04, windows, vmware, ip

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with vmware on windows 8.1. After tried everything i'm desperate about setting an static ip for Ubuntu.
This is my windows (host) ipconfig:

Windows `ipconfig` data

[image]

An that's what i wrote at **/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.100.16
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.100.2
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
```

tried with this gateway too, but doesn't works

```
gateway 192.168.100.2
```

The problem is that I can't get internet connexion with this configuration at ubuntu vm.
I'll appreciate any help

Comment: Um, have your tried telling your VM that the internet is ethernet, or dsl, if it knows its already plugged in and you have internet on your windows, it should just transfer over from one to the other. Mine have always auto detected it, and shown that it was plugged in and then I went form there.  Also asking for help is great, its how you learn, but be-careful how much you put out. Keep somethings to yourself, unless you have already customized your modem, or have a VPN :: food for thought- http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hackers-use-your-ip-address-hack-your-computer-stop-0130719/